# quick/intuitive Ngon drawing tool in blender

Tags: modeling

I am currenly using an inbuilt modelling tool in Unity but its a bit clunky so i would rather use blender. problem is there doesnt seem to be a way to quickly draw ngons in blender which i can then extrude. the best way i have so far is to draw a single vert and then extrude that abut as needed but its quite sluggish and not very intuitive. is there a better way of accomplising this or an addon anyone can recommend?just haveing a kind of pen tool which created and connected the verts wherever you place them would be what i am after. many thanks.

update: ive found a way of doing it by converting a curve into a mesh but even with very simple shapes it leaves behind many verts. ive included a picture to illustrate.

[image]

Comment: After you've extruded your first vert you can then move the mouse to the position that you want the next one and Ctrl-Right-click to extrude to that position. When you have your area plotted out select the first and last vert and hit F to join them, then select All and F to fill the area if you want a face.

Comment: Is this the [Curve Pen Tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/tools/pen.html), with Curve Resolution set to 1, for straight-line segments, if wamted?

Comment: @Robin Betts curve pen worked , many thanks.